# lighttpd redirect and rewrite to internal server

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd, mod-proxy

I am attempting to set up a proxy + rewrite with lighttpd.

I am trying to reverse proxy to two separate servers. The first is meant to be at root (192.168.1.198:7000) and the second is meant to be accessed through the /ram/ directory (192.168.1.197:8000). I am using version 1.4.38-1 of lighttpd and do not have the option of upgrading.

The below is the relevant portion of my lighttpd.config, I am hoping someone can point me to my error!

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":82" {
  url.rewrite-once = ( "^/ram/(.*)$" => "/$1" )
  proxy.server  = ( "" => (
    "" =>
      ( "host" => "192.168.1.197",
        "port" => 8000
      )
    )
  )
}
else $HTTP["host"] == "subdomain.example.com" {
  proxy.balance = "hash"
  proxy.server  = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "192.168.1.198", "port" => 7000 ) ) )

  $HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/ram/)" {
    proxy.server  = ( "" => (
      "" =>
        ( "host" => "127.0.0.1",
          "port" => 81
        )
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I see three backend proxy servers configured, not two.

Also, all requests from a client to port :82 on your server will be handled by the first conditional block.  The 'else $HTTP["host"] == "subdomain.example.com"' will never be seen by clients connecting to port :82 on your lighttpd server.

If you want all requests with Host: subdomain.example.com to follow the instructions in that conditional block, then make that section a standalone 'if' rather than an 'else' tacked on to the first condition ($SERVER["socket"] == ":82")